# Display GL_QUADS for ground

Tags: c++, opengl

I want to make gl_quads instead of gl_lines for ground in my game. The gl_lines is originally in the gl_quads position, showing a grid surface. I want to put gl_quads so i can add color into it. Is this correct?

```
//original code
void makeGrid(float size){
glColor4f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f -radarVisionMagnitude);
glBegin(GL_LINES);
for(int i=-size;i<=size;++i) {
    glVertex3f(i,0,-size);
    glVertex3f(i,0,size);

    glVertex3f(size,0,i);
    glVertex3f(-size,0,i);
}
glEnd();
}
```

//And the modified code

```
void makeGrid(float size){
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
for(int i=-size;i<=size;++i) 
{
    glColor4f(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,1.0f);
    glVertex3f(size,0,i);
    glVertex3f(-size,0,i);
    glVertex3f(i,0,-size);
    glVertex3f(i,0,size);
}
glEnd();
}
```

Comment: Why can't you see for yourself? Looks OK to me.

Comment: do u know how to delete this question? Its ok but when when i enable GL_FOG it doesnt display,so I just disabled that. Thanks nyway :)